# Vue.js Component rendering after prop update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In Vue.js i have a component (Answer Component) like this:

```
<template>
    <a class="quiz-input-choice" :class="{'quiz-input-choice--selected': answer.selected}"
       @click="toggleSelect()" :selected="answer.selected">
        <img :src="answer.image_path"/>
        <p class="quiz-input-choice__description">{{answer.title}}</p>
    </a>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['answer'],
        methods: {
            toggleSelect() {
                this.$parent.$emit('answer-selected', this.answer.id);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

If in the parent (Question Component) I update the "selected" attribute of the element, this component will not be rerendered.

```
export default {
        props: ['question'],
        components: {QuizAnswer},
        created: function () {
            let _self = this;
            this.$on('answer-selected', id => {
                let i = _self.question.answers.map(item => item.id).indexOf(id);
                let answer = _self.question.answers[i];
                answer.selected = !answer.selected;
            });
        }
    }
```

In Vue Developer Console, i checked that Answer component data are updated, so the answer is marked as selected. Anyway, is not rendered with the "quiz-input-choice--selected" class.

If, strangely, I update from the parent other attribute of the prop (for example (answer.title), then the child component is rendered correctly with also the class "quiz-input-choice--selected".
So i guess it's a problem of detecting changes from the child.

Comment: Sidenote: You don't need the `_self = this` pattern, since you are using an arrow function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everybody for the answers.

I discovered the problem. The "selected" attribute of the answer was not present in the initial object, so Vue cannot make reactive that attribute.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

I solved making reactive that property in the parent component.

```
created() {
            let self = this;
            this.question.answers.forEach(function (answer) {
                self.$set(answer, 'selected', false);
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a structural issue here. You shouldn't submit an event to your parent, since the component is supposed to be self-contained.

What you can do however is emitting an event in the child component (Answer) that will be catch in the parent (Question).

`Answer.vue`

```
<template>
    <a class="quiz-input-choice" :class="{'quiz-input-choice--selected': answer.selected}"
       @click="toggleSelect()" :selected="answer.selected">
        <img :src="answer.image_path"/>
        <p class="quiz-input-choice__description">{{answer.title}}</p>
    </a>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['answer'],
        methods: {
            toggleSelect() {
                this.$emit('answer-selected');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

`Question.vue`

Your template will have be catching the event like this (I don't know where your answers are so I assume that you have a `answers` array) :

```
<answer 
  v-for="(answer, index) in answers"
  :answer="answer" 
  @answer-selected="answerSelected(index)"
></answer>
```

And your script will look like this :

```
export default {
  props: ['question'],
  components: {QuizAnswer},
  data() {
    return {
      answers: [],
      selectedAnswer: -1,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    selectedAnswer(newIndex, oldIndex) {
      if (oldIndex > -1 && this.answers.length > oldIndex) {
        // Reset old value
        this.answers[oldIndex].selected = false;
      }
      if (newIndex > -1 && this.answers.length > newIndex) {
        // Set new value
        this.answers[newIndex].selected = true;
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    answerSelected(index) {
      this.selectedAnswer = index;
    },
  },
};
```